# Disabled attribute on html select option not working in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery, google-chrome

I'm developing a web app that will primarily be accessed via mobile browsers. At some point user selects a date and based on that, the app fetches data from an API and based on the result, sets certain options in another `<select>` element to disabled using jQuery: `$(#time-slot option:contains('some-text')).attr('disabled', true);`

Now, in desktop browsers, these disabled options are actually disabled, inspection shows the attribute `disabled='disabled'`, everything works fine. but when I test it on chrome for Android, all the options are available (the browser displays the native popup with the options).
Is this simply the way browsers on mobile work? Is there some way to disable certain options in this scenario or is it better to just make some custom select-like controls from scratch?

**EDIT:** also tried with `.prop()` jQuery method, and with `('disabled', 'disabled')`, the point is, it works fine on desktop, but the problem is with Android browsers.

Comment: Set the disabled attribute with the value disabled rather than true.

Comment: @John tried that as well, didn't work...

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle with your issue.

Comment: @John here https://jsfiddle.net/luinnarn/o59wf72r/1/

Comment: Works for me in google chrome on android. Maybe you're on a really outdated version of Google Chrome?

Comment: @John the JSFiddle worked for me too, so after some investigation it turned out the wrong endpoint for the data was being called from mobile due to the way it was deployed (the base url was hard-coded, duh!) so after that was fixed, everything worked normally. Thanks either way.